# jquery fail to get element's value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have following code. But it seems variable v is always null. And so select2 can't fetch json response. What's wrong with my method getting the other element's value?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = $('select#box_name').find('option:selected').val();

  $('#box_assoc_items').select2({
    placeholder: 'choose items',
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "/dishes/"+v+"/get_assoc_items.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function(term, page) {
        return { q: term, page: page, per: 10
        }
      },
       results: function(data, page) {
        return { results: data }
      }
    }
  });  
});
</script>

<%= simple_form_for([@restaurant, @order, @box]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, :collection => @dishes %>
  <%= f.input :assoc_items, :input_html => {:type => "hidden", :maxlength => 2, :style => 'width:400px'} %>
  <%= bootstrap_button(f, "Add a dish") %>
<% end %>
```

The equivalent html is as follow:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/restaurants/5/orders/4/boxes" class="simple_form new_box" id="new_box" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="zd3shkqtmbfFe3Sl3aoG39gQj1mslX7FHPHGJsgqxzQ=" /></div>
<div class="input select optional box_name">
  <label class="select optional" for="box_name">Name</label>
  <select class="select optional" id="box_name" name="box[name]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="9">combo 3</option>
    <option value="10">test dish</option>
    <option value="11">test 20</option></select></div>
<div class="input string optional box_assoc_items">
  <label class="string optional" for="box_assoc_items">Assoc items</label>
  <input class="string optional" id="box_assoc_items" maxlength="2" name="box[assoc_items]" size="50" style="width:400px" type="hidden" /></div>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
<input class="button btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Box" />    
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the selected option as soon as you load the document. Presumably you want to perform this action when an option is chosen. For this you bind the `.change()` event on your select, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select#box_name').on( 'change', function() {

        var v = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        $('#box_assoc_items').select2({
            placeholder: 'choose items',
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
              url: "/dishes/"+v+"/get_assoc_items.json",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: function(term, page) {
                return { q: term, page: page, per: 10
                }
              },
            results: function(data, page) {
                return { results: data }
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your view is initially loaded without any `option` selected for `#box_name`.  You must be seeing empty option in the `#box_name` `select` field.

For every selection change, you need to put your code in the `onchange` event as following:

```
$('#box_name').change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();

  $('#box_assoc_items').select2({
    placeholder: 'choose items',
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "/dishes/"+v+"/get_assoc_items.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function(term, page) {
        return { q: term, page: page, per: 10
        }
      },
       results: function(data, page) {
        return { results: data }
      }
    }
  });
});
```